# Postgresql Merging Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, merge, plpgsql

Given Table A and Table B below, could someone please guide me to what SQL/PLPGSQL I should use to produce the required result. Many thanks.

**TABLE A**

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| USR_ID | COL1  | COL2  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |       |  101  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |       |  101  |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

**TABLE B**

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| USR_ID | COL1  | COL2  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  103  |       |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    3   |  102  |       |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

**REQUIRED RESULT**

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| USR_ID | COL1  | COL2  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    1   |  103  |  101  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    2   |       |  101  |
+--------+-------+-------+
|    3   |  102  |       |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `coalesce` to give non-null values precedence

```
select coalesce(a.usr_id,b.usr_id) usr_id,
coalesce(a.col1,b.col1) col1,
coalesce(a.col2,b.col2) col2
from tablea a full join tableb b
on a.usr_id = b.usr_id
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate your immediate feedback.